# Using C# Directory/File operations to copy Sharepoint directories is failing because requires login

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a process that uses the UNC paths for sharepoint (instead of http://mysite.sharepoint/ it uses \mysite.sharepoint).  Using Windows Explorer, I have no problem browsing to my sharepoint's document libraries.  But when I do it programmatically there are issues.  The problem that I am noticing is that it says access is denied.  If I browse to the site using windows explorer once and then re-run my code, I have no issues.  I am pretty certain that what is happening, is the windows authentication information is not being passed across programmatically, but if i open it locally first then that initial handshake has already happened and the code now doesn't have to make that security check.

Obviously, I need it to be able to work every time the code runs.  Is there something in code I can do that would establish a connection first, so that File.Copy and Directory.GetDirectories/GetFiles just work the first time?

Comment: Can we see your code?